# What is the difference between Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Questions on Launchpad?

Tags: discussion, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we use Launchpad Answers and when Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/675/when-should-we-use-launchpad-answers-and-when-ask-ubuntu)

It seems that Ask Ubuntu and Questions for Ubuntu on Launchpad at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu cater to the same type of questions. What is the difference between the two, in the sense that in which of the two should I post my questions? Is there any duplication of effort?

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. Despite what the post you pointed out claims, I found similar questions on both sites, hence my posting this question. There are several questions on Launchpad which are not connected to bug reports but are as general as the ones here. Also, the Launchpad site is mentioned in the standard Kubuntu Support page.

Comment: This is practical, answerable, but is not '[based on actual problems that you face](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)', and so it's not a good fit here. Fine question, but there isn't a place for it here on the main page. Meta, maybe.

Comment: @EliahKagan This question is perfect for Meta. It also fails to articulate a 'problem', which is one of the points I considered (it's also **highlighted** in the FAQ so someone else thought it important). Your point is understood but there is no getting around the fact that questions *about* Ask Ubuntu belong on Meta, simple as that. Again referring to the FAQ *'If you have a question about the site that is not answered in this FAQ, check our community-maintained FAQ, and more generally our meta-discussion site.'*

Comment: @TomBrossman You've captured our point of disagreement perfectly. **I don't think this question is about Ask Ubuntu.** I think this is a question about help resources in the Ubuntu community (not just Ask Ubuntu, but also Launchpad Answers), which makes it appropriate for main, not meta. In any case, this disagreement won't be resolved in comments, and I am perhaps to be faulted for carrying it on here as long as I have. **I'll try to post a new meta question about this issue, sometime soon.**

Answer (score 6):

**Asking questions on Launchpad:**

- You contact developers directly. That means you will probably get the most accurate and technically correct answer.
- Your question may get redirected to developers of specific project your question concerns.
- The question cannot be guaranteed to be answered soon, keep in mind developers are busy making Ubuntu awesome.
- There are no formatting options when asking/answering.
- There are mechanisms that sometimes allow you to ask in your native language.
- Questions on Launchpad can be easily converted into bug reports.
- It may happen that developers will provide you with poor answer, due to their lack of time or resources.

**Asking questions on AskUbuntu:**

- You ask the Ubuntu community. That **may** include developers, but in most cases your questions are answered by Ubuntu experts and fans.
- You can expect to have your question answered within days, or even within minutes! That is because there is many many times more people that can answer you here.
- Questions and answers may be formatted, include pictures, lists etc.
- It is possible that the answer will be incorrect, as there is noone to guarantee its quality.

  - On the other hand, other users may improve such answer or correct it.
- You can be the one answering too. That's a great way to provide others with support.
- Witty comments, sharing off-topic experience, reputation scoring and badges - all that makes AskUbuntu community an enjoyable environment, as opposed to Launchpad's plain interface.

Comment: You can be the one answering too as well on Launchpad - just leave a comment.

Answer (score -4):

**Launchpad** is a software collaboration platform that provides:
*Bug tracking*

*Code hosting using Bazaar*

*Code reviews*

*Ubuntu package building and hosting*

*Translations*

*Mailing lists*

*Answer tracking and FAQs*

*Specification tracking**

Other hand **Askubuntu**

This is a free, community driven Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers. It is a part of the [Stack Exchange network of Q&A websites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), and it was created through the open democratic process defined at [Stack Exchange Area 51.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

*It  synthesize aspects of Wikis, Blogs, Forums, and Digg/Reddit in a way that we think is original.*
[image]

In my personal experiences here you get fast answer if you have good question

Comment: I do not believe this answers the OP question. It does not seem to be about what each site is; instead, it looks like a question about what kind of question to ask here and what kind of question to ask there.